# Generic identity function for use with type inference

Tags: c#, generics, identity, functional-programming, type-inference

I was wondering if it is possible, as my 5 minutes of experimentation proved fruitless.

I hoped it would be as easy as:

```
T Identity<T>(T t) { return t; }
```

But this fails to compile on generic methods taking Func parameters. Eg OrderBy. Even specifying type parameters (which is exactly what I want to avoid!), it fails to compile.

Next I tried something I thought would work:

```
Func<T, R> MakeIdentity<T, R>()
{
  return (T t) => (R)(object)t;
}
```

Also no go  :(  (this compiles when applying type parameters, again, not what I want)

Has anyone had luck making such a thing?

UPDATE: please dont say: x => x, I know that, it's obvious!  I am asking for a function, not an expression  :)

UPDATE 2: When I refer to identity, I mean in the functional sense, where the function simply returns the same object that you passed to it. It is probably in every functional language I have come across, but those do not use static typing. I am wondering how to do this (if possible) with generics. Just for fun!

UPDATE 3: Here's a partial 'solution' based on the 2nd idea:

```
Expression<Func<T, T>> MakeIdentity<T>()
{
  return t => t;
}

void Foo(string[] args)
{
  var qargs = args.AsQueryable();
  var q = qargs.OrderBy(MakeIdentity<string>());
  ...
}
```

I dont think anything more than this will be possible.

Comment: Getting tired of writing x => x  :)  And just wondering really. it serves no purpose.

Comment: With C# 6.0 `myList.OrderBy(Identity);` will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type inference will not work since host method and input method both are generic. To do this you must write

```
myList.OrderBy<int, int>(Identity);
```

Or

```
myList.OrderBy((Func<int, int>)Identity);
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me in places I've needed it so far.

```
internal class IdentityFunction<TSource>
{
    public static Func<TSource, TSource> Instance
    {
        get { return x => x; }
    }
}

OrderBy(IdentityFunction<Foo>.Instance)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that anonymous functions and method groups in C# do not participate in type inference.  Explicit types must be given.

What you can do though is have Identity functions for anonymous functions.  Example

```
Func<T> IdentityFunc1<T>(Func<T> func) { return func; }
```

I'm not entirely sure what you're getting at with the second sample.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: I think you understand identity wrong. It's a commonly used function in functional language, that simply returns what you give it.

Answer (score 0):

The first option works for me:

```
public class Foo {

   public Foo(Func<MyObj, MyObj> map) {... }

}

public class Client {

   private static T Identity<T>(T t) { return t; }

   public void main() {
      var foo = new Foo(Identity);

      var c = from f in Enumerable.Range(0, 100) select Identity(f);
      c.ToList().ForEach(System.Console.Out.WriteLine);
   }
}
```